# split and concatenate and update in a column of same row oracle

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Split a column based on delimiter "," and then split within the results with delimiter " - ". Get all the first element of the second split concatenate with delimiter "," and update it to the column in the same row

```
ID Supplier_ID_NAME 
1  1234 - Supplier 1,2145 - Supplier 3
2  1235 - Supplier 2
3  1246 - Supplier 4,1234 - Supplier 1, 1478 - Supplier 5
```

What i need is

```
ID Supplier_id
1  1234,2145
2  1235
3  1246,1234,1478
```

I could split the values using delimiter "," but this query is getting me only the first element of the split. Ex for ID: 1 in example above it is getting me only 1234

```
select id,Supplier_id, regexp_substr (
           Supplier_ID_NAME ,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           length ( Supplier_ID_NAME ) - length ( replace ( Supplier_ID_NAME, ',' ) ) + 1) from  suppliers_tbl;
```

How to split by , and then split by " - " and then concatenate and update a column

Comment: Storing data in delimited strings is not considered good practice as you cannot maintain the referential integrity of the data you are storing. It would be much better to use a second table and store each term in a separate row.

Comment: Yes after split or replace, we will be merging with another table as separate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother splitting, just replace everything from after the digits until the comma in each term.

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(supplier_id_name, '\s*(\d+)[^,]*', '\1') AS supplier_id
FROM   suppliers_tbl;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE suppliers_tbl (ID, Supplier_ID_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, '1234 - Supplier 1,2145 - Supplier 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1235 - Supplier 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '1246 - Supplier 4,1234 - Supplier 1, 1478 - Supplier 5' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | SUPPLIER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234,2145 |
| 2 | 1235 |
| 3 | 1246,1234,1478 |

If you want to `UPDATE` the table then:

```sql
UPDATE suppliers_tbl
SET    supplier_id_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(supplier_id_name, '\s*(\d+)[^,]*', '\1');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lFGwTX_w)

Comment: Awesome solution, i dint think of replace option, i was thinking only split and concatenate. Appreciated and thanks