# Need to extract value from key-value pair data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column that contains the value in the key-value pair. But I need to extract only value from that column.

Input Table:

```
+------+---------------------------------+
| Col1 |              Col2               |
+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | key1:Val1;Key2:Val2;;;Key5:Val5 |
+------+---------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 |              Col2              | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | key1:Val1;Key2:Val2;;Key4:Val4 | Val1 | Val2 |      | Val4 |
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Explanation:

As `Col2` contains the value in key-value pair out of which I need to extract only `value` and store it in a different column and wherever there is no value we need to put it as blank. So basically, need to identify `;` and `:`.

My attempt:

```
SELECT
  Col1,
  SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, 'Key1:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 5) AS Col2
From table_name;

DB - Oracle Sql Developer tool
Version - 19c
```

I am not sure whether this is the optimized way to handle this requirement and hence seeking help for the same.

Comment: Please describe the issue you are trying to solve. Do you have any performance issues? How much input rows do you have? Are you facing some parse issues for specific values? You may rewrite this code using `SUBSTR/INSTR`, but it will be less readable and worth nothing for tables with few thousands of rows

Comment: This is not optimal, because the underlying structure (using a string to hold multiple values) is an anti-pattern. That should be fixed to use actual relational database constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you are using is broadly correct but there are a few minor issues:

1. You do not anchor the pattern to a start of a term so if you have the data `kkey1:not this;key1:this` and you search for `key1` then you will partially match the `kkey1` key and get the wrong value.
2. Your data has a mix of title- and lower-case keys and you are only searching for title-case key names.
3. It is unclear why you are using `SUBSTR` as you are extracting the capturing group from the regular expression and not the entire match so you do not need to remove the key prefix.

If you want to `UPDATE` the table (i.e. store it in a different column) then use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
  SET col3 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key1:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
      col4 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key2:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
      col5 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key3:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
      col6 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key4:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2),
      col7 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key5:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  col1 VARCHAR2(20),
  col2 VARCHAR2(100),
  col3 VARCHAR2(20),
  col4 VARCHAR2(20),
  col5 VARCHAR2(20),
  col6 VARCHAR2(20),
  col7 VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2)
  VALUES (1, 'key1:Val1;Key2:Val2;;;Key5:Val5');
```

Then, after the `UPDATE`, the table contains:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | key1:Val1;Key2:Val2;;;Key5:Val5 | Val1 | Val2 | *null* | *null* | Val5 |

If you just want a `SELECT` statement then use the same `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function calls as the `UPDATE` in the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key1:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) AS col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key2:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) AS col4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key3:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) AS col5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key4:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) AS col6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)key5:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) AS col7
FROM  table_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XP2O3gEH)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I need a generic ```SELECT``` query which will suffice this requirement. Do I need to write REGEXP_SUBSTR for each key value pair? What if there are 10 key-value pairs in that column?

Comment: @Vicky See the updated answer (but, yes, you would use 10 `REGEXP_SUBSTR`).

Comment: @vicky your final point is exactly why you shouldn't store multiple values as a delimited string in a relational database. SQL is a strongly and statically typed language, in this case that means a query's resulting number of columns is ***not*** dynamic. For dynamic numbers of values, store your data in a normalised structure (one row per value, not one column per value)

Comment: @MT0 - Do we need to give exact string for the ```keys``` like in this case key1, key2..

Comment: @Vicky If you want to extract the `key1` value into `col3` then you need to correlate that in the query so, yes. If you do not mean that then I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to put the first key-value pair into `col3` and then the second key-value pair into `col4`, etc. then you could do that but you would then be in a situation where, if the data is in a different order, sometimes you have `key1` in `col3` and sometimes it is a different key [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JAc8N5tq).

Comment: @MT0 If I need to fetch key1 value and not the Val1, Val2 then in this case what needs to be done

Comment: @Vicky That appears to be exactly what the answer does. I'm not sure I am understanding your question.

Comment: @MT0 - If the input string is in the format
```Val1:Key1;Val2:Key2``` likewise and from here I need to extract ```Val1, Val2``` etc

Comment: @Vicky If you want a delimited list with all the values and no keys in the same order as the original list then just use `REGEXP_REPLACE` similar to [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441706/1509264) yesterday. If you want to get the values in key order then extract individual values using the above query and concatenate into a new list. If you want something else then you probably need to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) because this answer has answered the question you asked and the comments are going away from that question.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks alot for your inputs. I accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using `JSON_TABLE` to split the semicolon separated column into rows, then apply `REGEXP_REPLACE` to extract value from the key-value pair :

```
SELECT COL1, 
       COL2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ELEMENT, '^.*:', '') END) COL3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ELEMENT, '^.*:', '') END) COL4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 5 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ELEMENT, '^.*:', '') END) COL5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 6 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ELEMENT, '^.*:', '') END) COL6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 7 THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ELEMENT, '^.*:', '') END) COL7
FROM (
  SELECT COL1, COL2, 2+ID AS ID, ELEMENT
  FROM mytable t
  CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( '["' || REPLACE(col2, ';', '","') || '"]'  , '$[*]'
                COLUMNS (
                      ID FOR ORDINALITY,
                      ELEMENT VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$')
               ) j
) s
GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B0qla8KQ)